# Adding file to WSS 3.0 document library without GUI

Tags: sharepoint

OK I am new to working with SHarePoint Services and have an issue that I am trying to overcome. Where I work, I have implemented a Crystal reports Scheduler that outputs the reports to a shared folder. What I am trying to accomplish now is finding a way that I can point the output of the scheduler to the document library. I was hoping that I could find it like any other shared folder.

Comment: Ryan, could you please try to re-explain what you are trying to do. As far as I understand you want to make your CR scheduler (is that like a job?)  ouput its files into a doc lib in sharepoint via code. Have you looked into the web services for that. Otherwise you have to run your code on the SP server in order to get access to the WSS/MOSS API (can you do that or are you looking to do that?)

Comment: This was answered below (although he never marked it such yet)

Answer (score 2):

1. On your box hosting sharepoint, turn on the WebClient Service.
2. Goto the library you wish to upload to, drop down on actions-> open in windows explorer
3. The path you see can be converted to a UNC path, where you can use it like any other shared folder.

   - To convert, it should look like \\servername\Shared Documents
   - This unc can be mapped as a shared folder like any other physical networked folders.
4. Happy Uploading!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload the file in your code (not manually) without mounting a WebDAV share, you can also HTTP-PUT it to the desired URL, for example http://myserver/sites/mysite/mysubsite/mylist/myfolder/foo.doc

Comment: OK I am trying to do this first without code the same way that I can navigate to any shared drive. I followed Jason's directions yesterday and got it to work for the default site, but when I created another site, there is now a port number in the path and I seem to be having issues with this.

Comment: Ryan, are you using a DNS server?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in this question: [Uploading files to Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) document library using HTTP PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596315/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-wss-3-0-document-library-using-http-put)

With the tip in this answer: [Uploading files to Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) document library using HTTP PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596315/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-wss-3-0-document-library-using-http-put/2663918#2663918).