# How to delete documents from a document library in WSS 3.0?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I need a way to programmaticaly delete documents from Sharepoint 2007 document library. I don't have access to the server to deploy server-side code, so it needs to be via web service or [pure http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596315/uploading-files-to-sharepoint-wss-3-0-document-library-using-http-put). I can find plenty of examples for removing attachments from list items, but nothing for removing from document libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing documents from libraries it actually comes to removing items from a list, since this is only a specific case of list items. You might google for that.

Example:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/c19cf6d0-17ca-40d3-9c53-16ebea5727b6