# ASP.Net MVC 4 for PUT request response 409 - Conflict

Tags: c#, api, http, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We're working on a project with a **asp.net mvc 4** site and mobile applications for ios and Android. We wanted to make the **API**(for the mobile apps) **and the site working with a shared code base**.
We created an API area where the "bussiness logic" and api responses are written, and the website uses these classes. Besides there are route options to use these as API.

GET and POST methods are working perfectly, everything works like charm, but when it comes to **PUT** - the update methods - it **crashes**.

Firstly we've got a 403 error code saying write access is forbidden(actually it's just database modification, so we didn't understand what it could be). It changed when we allowed writing for the app folder in IIS.

Now we get a "**HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict**" for every PUT method request. We've tried and read almost everything we found. Does anybody have an idea what can cause this problem?

**EDIT:**
Here's some code:
The action:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [ApiAuth]
    [ActionName("Workitem")]
    public bool Workitem(int id, [FromBody]WorkItem model)
    {
        WorkItem item = Db.WorkItems.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            Logger.Warn("JobRoute/PutWorkItem: not found workitem");
            throw ErrorHelper.CreateApiException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not found workitem");
        }
        PreparePut(item);
        item.Active = model.Active;
        item.Name = model.Name;
        Db.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {
            Db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            Logger.Warn("PUT User/User: Workitem not found");
            throw ErrorHelper.CreateApiException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Workitem not found");
        }
    }
```

This is the model.

```
public class WorkItem : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InsertDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastChangeDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

protected void PreparePut(BaseModel model)
    {
        PrepareModificationDate(model);
    }

protected void PrepareModificationDate(BaseModel model)
    {
        model.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

The strange thing it works on localhost, after publish it doesn't.

http://domain.com/api/work/workitem/{id}
[PUT]
for authorization we give an extra HTTP Header for a token.

Body:
Name=Test+Name&Active=true

The raw form:

```
PUT http://domain.com/api/work/workitem/1
HTTP/1.1 Host: domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
X-Auth-Session: c796a0a5c1ea9395196bf47abdbb273a
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=eRxqkQZMPrRvY-ugp2tkge5UuAxS3arksJh7H17GE_H_ytSd_gLwpzTD3H276MoIgmyugoI3dMjh6M0Ursqomg2; ASP.NET_SessionId=dibvmeuiojsmphefbiifvkso

Name=Teszt&Active=true
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 15:20:22 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 43
Via: 1.1 domain.com
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

<body><h2>HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict</h2></body>
```

Comment: Show us a sample PUT request that fails; Show us your Controller code and the Model it is updating, as well as the ORM or database code to save this entity. A [409 Conflict has a specific meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785036/reasons-for-a-409-conflict-http-error-when-uploading-a-file-to-sharepoint-using), but we can't see what in your code is causing that if we don't see the code.

Comment: edited with extra infos

Comment: Can you share the raw request? You can use POSTMan for Google Chrome to generate one.

Comment: There it is. I saw some similar cases. The difference was that the Connection was "Closed" and not "Keep-Alive". Can this cause the problem?

Comment: What does your PreparePut method do?

Comment: BaseModel determines Insert and LastChangeDate and Id. PreparePut modifies the LastChangeDate to DateTime.Now

Comment: You should add that method to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an IIS configuration problem. It needed an extra dll for ISAPI:

Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

Answer (score 1):

I've been hit by similar problem but for me the reason was different. I'm using webapi with restful paths, and `PUT` is used to update a resource (specified similar to `/api/products/id`). Everything was working fine until I moved into prod env., then I started to receive `409 Conflict`.

As it turned out, prod server (IIS 7.5) had `WebDav` installed and `WebDav` module/handler was intercepting `PUTs` causing the app to break. Disabling `WebDav` (at site level) and removing WebDav modules/handlers solved the issue.

*(There is a lot of information floating around on `WebDav` interfering with `RESTful`, but I was not able to find anything specifically mentioning `409 Conflict` in this context so I hope this will be useful for future visitors)*

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of an HTTP 409 being returned from an ASP.NET MVC web method where you're saving data to a database: ASP.NET MVC may return an HTTP 409 response to a call in which an unhandled `DbUpdateException` occurs due to a foreign key error.

If you catch the `DbUpdateException` in your server-side code, the inner exception should have the details of the error information provided by your database.