# Error due to Status code 409 when running jMeter script

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm executed the jMeter script and it returns response of 409, 404 or 500.

The below is the response of one of the request:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-07-20 12:28:32 IST
Load time: 1028
Connect Time: 278
Latency: 616
Size in bytes: 59337
Sent bytes:824
Headers size in bytes: 815
Body size in bytes: 58522
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 409
Response message: Conflict

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 06:58:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-ATG-Version: version=QVRHUGxhdGZvcm0vMTEuMixDb21tZXJjZVJlZmVyZW5jZVN0b3JlLzExLjI=
Set-Cookie: userPrefLanguage=en_GB; expires=Sat, 26-Mar-2067 02:58:31 +00:00; path=/store/; HttpOnly
X-ATG-Version: version=QVRHUGxhdGZvcm0vMTEuMixDb21tZXJjZVJlZmVyZW5jZVN0b3JlLzExLjI=
Set-Cookie: userPrefLanguage=en_GB; expires=Sat, 26-Mar-2067 02:58:31 +00:00; path=/store/; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Tue, 04 Dec 1993 21:29:02 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: User-Agent
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

How to solve the above?

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating resource which is older than existing resource.

see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409). and other [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785036/reasons-for-a-409-conflict-http-error-when-uploading-a-file-to-sharepoint-using).

> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For
>   example, you may get a 409 response when uploading a file which is
>   older than the one already on the server resulting in a version
>   control conflict.