# Not receiving error response from API in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, http, angular-httpclient

I'm calling an API in Angular and trying to get the response body, but it just displays `error message is [object Object]`

I've tried just doing `console.log(error)`, `error.text()` ,`JSON.parse(error._body).errors` ,`error.error` ,`error.message` and `error.json()`but none worked.

This is my code, would really appreciate some help:

```
  doImport = (dataObj) => {
    for(let i = 0; i<this.uploadedFilesCount; i++) {
      const filename = this.uploadedFileNames[i];
      this.disableDeployCTA = true;
      const params:string = filename + "/" + this.testStartTime + "/" + this.userNtId + "/" + this.userTeamID + "/" + this.userTeam; 
      var res = '';
      this.httpService.importUML(params).subscribe((response: any) => {        
        this.toastmessage.success('Successfully created test #'+i); 
        this.toastmessage.clear();
      },                              
      (error) => {
        console.log("error message is "+error.message);
        if(error.status == 409) {
          if(res.indexOf("static data")!=-1) {
            this.toastmessage.error(filename + ": That static data exists already!");
          }
          else {
            this.toastmessage.error(filename + ": That test case exists already! Please change test case name.");
          }
        }
        else if(error.status == 400) {
          this.toastmessage.error(filename + ": Incorrectly formatted UML. Please fix and try again.");
        }
      });
    }
    this.resetAxiForm();
    this.disableImport = true; 
  }
```

And the error response I want to get:

[image]

When I do console.log(error):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty common mistake in `console.log`, what's happening here is that the error you are receiving is actually an `object`, and what you are doing with that `+` sign is concatenating `string` with an `object` which will surely display `[object Object]`, **what you need to do is use a comma `,` instead of `+` inside `console.log()`**.

Replace `console.log("error message is "+error.message);` with `console.log("error message is ", error.message);`

Hope this helped.

Comment: that did help, thank you! Sadly it still doesn't receive the response body, It just displays "axis.component.ts:507 error message is  Http failure response for [server]: .409 Conflict". Do you happen to know how to retrieve that response?

Comment: @anoncomp - Are you logging the entire `error object` not only the `error.message`?

Comment: @anoncomp - Try logging the entire error object and paste the error here please

Comment: @anoncomp - are you using a `PUT` request in your `service`? Could you please share your `HttpService` code as well.

Comment: its a POST request! I pasted the image of the error object when I logged just the object. The POST method in httpService is `importUML(params) {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8081/bruml/import/' + params, "");
  }`

Comment: @anoncomp - Here's what i found regarding this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785036/reasons-for-a-409-conflict-http-error-when-uploading-a-file-to-sharepoint-using) hope this help you.

Comment: I know why the error is occurring, but I want to be able to print it in the console